# how can I use slug before patName in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using next.js and graphql now.

I need to set the workspace name in url.

```
localhost/[workspace slug]/memeber
localhost/[workspace slug]/admin
```

like that

Can you help me?

Comment: Hello 정태현 , welcome to stackoverflow! You need to include more code and explain the architecture of your project. Its very hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish or what problem needs to be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement dynaming routing you can use Next.js built in [routing system](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), for example with last version of next.js you can create a folder inside `pages` called `workspace`, inside `workspace` a folder called `[id]` which containes a file ex. `[role].js`.
So a route like `/workspace/1234/admin` will be automatically matched by the server.

Otherwise you can use a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) like express and use something like this:

```
  server.get('/:workspaceSlug/admin', (req, res) => {
    const { workspaceSlug} = req.params
    return app.render(req, res, '/admin', {workspaceSlug})
  })
  server.get('/:workspaceSlug/member', (req, res) => {
    const { workspaceSlug} = req.params
    return app.render(req, res, '/member', {workspaceSlug})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside folder "pages" create a folder called [slug]
In that folder create admin.js and member.js. This way you can access localhost/[slug]/member & localhost/[slug]/admin.

```
pages
  |--[slug]
       |--admin.js  
       |--member.js
```

Inside the page, you can retrieve the value of [slug] by using `useRouter`

admin.js

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Admin = (query) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin</h1>
      <p>{router.query.id}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

member.js:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Member = (query) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Member</h1>
      <p>{router.query.id}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Member;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named [slug] inside pages, inside that add your files.
After that you will be able to use your files for example:
localhost/men/member 
localhost/women/member